# SNS not able to hit HTTPS endpoint

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sns

I have below annotation set on my controller but it is not able to receive AWS SNS messages,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
```

SNS message sample is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html)

I always get **415 Unsupported Media Type**. Looks like I am missing some minor thing here.

Comment: I am afraid the problem is that you setup the contenttype as text/plan but aws is sending a different format, maybe JSON or XML probably

Answer (score 2):

**This what worked for me:**

The request body is actually a JSON string (text/plain) so you should accept it as a string and then parse it to a usable structure.

Here is an example.

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "text/plain")
void subscribe(@RequestBody String paramsString) {
    Map<String, String> params = new Gson().fromJson(paramsString, new 
HashMap<String, String>().getClass());
    // Use params..
}
```