# AWS SNS http suscription return "Unsupported Media Type: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sns

I have an SNS topic and an HTTP subscription, that call a Spring boot endpoint, my endpoint looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/path")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> action(@RequestBody Object body) {
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

I try to call this endpoint when I publish a message in this topic using AWS CLI like this:

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:000000000000:MyTopic \
    --message '{"name": "test"}' --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566
```

but I got an error:

```
Unsupported Media Type: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' is not supported
```

I add `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE` to my code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/path", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
```

But I got the same error.

For some reason, the topic sends the message using a different `text/plain` media type.

I learned this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html), and effectively the message is send using:

```
...
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
...
```

My question is there any way to force the SNS publisher to use `application/json`?

Or is there any way to solve the issue in my controller?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003926/sns-not-able-to-hit-https-endpoint

Comment: @JCompetence I already tried the same thing in the answer, except I used `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE` and in the answer, they used `text/plain`, anyway I tried also `text/plain` and it gives me the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved when I used `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE` and `@RequestBody String body`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/path", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> action(@RequestBody String body) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SNS now supports custom `Content-Type` headers for HTTP messages delivered from topics. Here's the announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-sns-content-type-request-headers-http-s-notifications/

You simply have to modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, `application/xml`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

```
{
    "healthyRetryPolicy": {
        "minDelayTarget": 1,
        "maxDelayTarget": 60,
        "numRetries": 50,
        "numNoDelayRetries": 3,
        "numMinDelayRetries": 2,
        "numMaxDelayRetries": 35,
        "backoffFunction": "exponential"
    },
    "throttlePolicy": {
        "maxReceivesPerSecond": 10
    },
    "requestPolicy": {
        "headerContentType": "application/json"
    }
}
```

You set the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute by calling the `SetSubscriptionAttributes` API action: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetSubscriptionAttributes.html